# Too many input arguments in imshow for matlab

Tags: image, matlab, arguments

When I call

```
imshow('test.png')
```

it returns the following error:

```
??? Error using ==> newplot
Too many input arguments.

Error in ==> basicImageDisplay at 9
hh = image(xdata,ydata,cdata, ...

Error in ==> imshow at 246
hh = basicImageDisplay(fig_handle,ax_handle,...
```

I have no idea why, please help me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem. It looks like I have another function named newplot in other projects, whose path is ahead of the image function in toolbox. Didn't realize it until re-install the matlab. Sorry for the silly mistake.